# jQuery Ajax callback to a class method seemingly calling wrong instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue instance with a Vuex Store.
Vue components can call a method on the Vue instance to ensure certain objects are present in the Vuex store. Each object is stored as an instance of a class ApiObject. If only the object's ID is known the object will be pulled from the server with a jQuery Ajax request.

The following issue occurs:

I have two ApiObjects with their respective object IDs of "0d3f7f10" and "f6a7d150". The first one is already present in the Vuex store but the second one is only known by it's id, so an Ajax reqeuest is triggered.

The object with the id "f6a7d150" starts the ajax request and hits the correct endpoint (/api/v1/f6a7d150) and then hits the callback function, which is a method of the ApiObject class.

But when the callback is called, I'm all of a sudden in the wrong instance of ApiObject. I would expect that I'm calling the ApiObject "f6a7d150"'s callback method but I'm hitting "0d3f7f10"'s callback method.

That's the API call and callback methods:

```
refresh () {
    console.log('Calling ' + this.id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: this.url(),
        method: 'GET',
        success: this.handleApiResult
    })
}

handleApiResult (result) {
    console.log('Handling ' + this.id);
    this.data = result['data'];
}
```

The expected console output would be:

```
Calling f6a7d150
Handling f6a7d150
```

But it actually is:

```
Calling f6a7d150
Handling 0d3f7f10
```

The result variable in handleApiResult holds the correct object with the ID "f6a7d150", so up until the API call we were in the correct instance.

When I dump the Vuex Store there are two objects with ID "0d3f7f10", one with data and the second one (which is the one we just pulled from the API) without data, so only it's ID is known.

The Vue components create objects in Vuex with these methods on my Vue instance. The console log reports, that objects with ID "f6a7d150" and "0d3f7f10" were created, so I have no idea, how there is no object with ID "f6a7d150" in my store.

```
ensureObject (type, id, data) {
    if (!type || (!id && !data)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!id) {
        id = data.id;
    }

    if (this.$store.state[type].filter(o => o.id === id).length < 1) {
        console.log("Creating " + id);
        this.$store.state[type].push(new CiliatusObject(type, id, data));
    }
},

ensureObjects (type, ids, data) {
    if (!ids && !data) {
        return;
    }

    if (!ids) {
        data.forEach(obj => this.ensureObject(type, null, obj));
    }
    else {
        let that = this;
        ids.forEach(function (id) {
            that.ensureObject(
                type,
                id,
                data ? data.filter(o => o && o.id === id)[0] : undefined
            )
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found it after banging my head against a wall for hours.

In a computed property of a Vue component, there was this line:

`let obj = this.$store.state.filter(s => s.id = this.id);`

Notice the `=`where you'd expect a `===`.....